# React js Image upload from dummy Json

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add image dynamically in my component. I have a dummy JSON file in my project folder and in that JSON file I'm having six fields among that one is Image field. I want to display that image along with data. I have looked for so many answers and applied that in my code but I didn't get the image loaded in the page. I've my image under "Public/Images" folder. And I have created a component called "Stock" and I've used map functionality to render the data from JSON file. I've added my code below could anyone can correct me where I'm missing the concept. Thanks in advance!

```
Stock Component:


const Ad = Data;

const images = require.context("../../public/Images", true);

export default class AllStock extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { SD: Ad };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.SD.map((dat, index) => (
          <p style={{ color: "red" }} key={index}>
            {" "}
            {dat.company}
            {/* <img src={require(`../Images/${dat.img}`)} width="100" /> */}
            {/* <img src={`../Images/{dat.img}`} /> */}
            <img src={dat.img} />
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Dummy JSON :

[
  {
    "id": "A01",
    "company": "Twitter Inc",
    "ticker": "TWTR",
    "img": "../../public/Images/A.jpg",
    "stockPrice": "22.76 USD",
    "timeElapsed": "5 sec ago"
  },

  {
    "id": "A02",
    "company": "Square Inc",
    "ticker": "SQ",
    "img": "../../public/Images/B.jpg",
    "stockPrice": "45.28 USD",
    "timeElapsed": "10 sec ago"
  },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove the "../../public/" from img and use as bellow

```
{
 "id": "A01",
 "company": "Twitter Inc",
 "ticker": "TWTR",
 "img": "Images/A.jpg",
 "stockPrice": "22.76 USD",
 "timeElapsed": "5 sec ago"
},
```